# Django ImportError at / no matter what I do

Tags: python, django

So I've just started playing around with Django and I decided to give it a try on my server. So I installed Django and created a new project, following the basics outlined in the tutorial on Djangoproject.com

Unfortunatly, no matter what I do, I can't get views to work: I constantly get

```
ImportError at /

No module named index
```

[Here](http://grabup.nakedsteve.com/4031375c5cdb6246abf2011e6cc69a8a.png) is a screenshot of this error

I've been googling and trying various commands with no luck, and I'm literally about to tear my hair out until I become bald. I've tried adding the django source directory, my project directory, and the app directory to PYTHONPATH with no luck. I've also made sure that **init**.py is in all of the directories (both project and app) Does anyone have any idea as to what could be going wrong here?

**UPDATES**

Sorry, I was in kind of a rush while posting this, here's some context:

The server I've been trying is just django's built in server using manage.py (python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000, since I need to access it externally) on linux (debian)

appdir/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Sup")

def test(request):
    return HttpRespons("heyo")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^****/', include('****.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^test/', include('mecore.views.test')),
    (r'^', include('mecore.views.index'))
)
```

Comment: Is there any more context you can give us? e.g. Which module is raising the ImportError. A stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Just updated, hopefully that'll help you guys out.

Comment: @Sliggy: Please don't post a screenshot of the error.  Copy and paste the actual text from the actual web page, it's more useful than a screen shot.

Comment: You may not have noticed, but you also spelled "HttpResponse" wrong in the test() method.  Missed the "e" on the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `urls.py` is wrong; you should consider reading [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#intro-tutorial03) and [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-urls).

You don't include a function; you include a module.  You name a function, `mecore.views.index`.  You only include entire modules `include('mecore.views')`.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^****/', include('****.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^test/', 'mecore.views.test'),
    (r'^', 'mecore.views.index')
)
```

Comment: I just added a few source files and some information, I think that should help us find the problem.

Comment: I love you. Like, seriously, I love you so much. Feel free to have my babies.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `__init__.py` in each of the mecore and views directories, as well as an index.py in views?

A directory is a package, from Python's viewpoint, only if it has a file named `__init__.py` (it may be empty, if you don't need to execute any special code when that package is imported, but it has to be there).

Edit: note that in `include` you must name the python path to a module, not to a function: see [Django's relevant docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) -- judging from your comment you appear to be mis-using `include`, as I see @S.Lott had surmised in his answer.

Comment: There is no mecore/views/ directory. There's only /mecore/ and views.py is a file in /mecore/ with all of the functions in it, as described in the Django tutorial (Part 3 I believe)

Comment: Hmmm, not with include() surely?  include() must contain the Python path to a module, not to a function.

Answer (score -1):

From [ImportError No module named views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011791/importerror-no-module-named-views):

> Try and move `views.py` to the "inner" mysite directory. Views are part of an application, hence the need to move them inside the application directory (and not in the project directory).
>
> The error message you get indicates that `mysite` (the application) has no `views.py` module.